# How can I pass a value from a 'Discovery rule' to the key of an 'Item prototype' in Zabbix?

Tags: zabbix

Good afternoon.
It is necessary to receive data from the Item and pass it to the "Discovery rules", and then use it in the key on each "Item prototypes".

1. I get the data of the "Item".

```
Type: Zabbix agent
Key: system.run["smartctl --scan-open"]
```

I get:

```
/dev/sda -d ata # /dev/sda, ATA device
/dev/sdb -d sat # /dev/sdb [SAT], ATA device
/dev/sdc -d sat # /dev/sdc [SAT], ATA device
```

2. I convert the result to the form (through preprocessing in JavaScript) to Json:

```
Preprocessing:
const sd = value.match(/sd(.)/g);
var data = [];
for (i = 0; i <= sd.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        data.push({"disk": sd[i]});
    }
}
data.pop();
return JSON.stringify(data);
```

I get:

```
[{"disk":"sda"},{"disk":"sdb"},{"disk":"sdc"}]
```

3. I create a "Discovery rule":

```
Type: Dependent items
LLD macros: LLD - {#DISK} and JSONPath - $..disk
```

4. I create a "Item prototypes":

```
Type: Zabbix agent
Key: system.run["smartctl -A /dev/[{$DISK}]"]
```

But data from №3 comes to №4 as **["sda"]**, but I need it as **sda**. For me to use them in the key of "Item prototypes". For example:

```
system.run["smartctl -A /dev/sda"]
```

Can you please tell me how to pass the value **sda** to the key of "Item prototypes"?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `dependent item` in this case. Put `zabbix agent` as type of the prototype item.

Update: the key is wrong:

```
- system.run["smartctl -A /dev/[{$DISK}]"]
+ system.run["smartctl -A /dev/{$DISK}"]
```

Comment: If I make point No. 1 in the "Discovery rule" (only not Json, but a list: sda,sdb,sdc), then how can I pass each value to the "Item prototypes"? To use in the key of the first element sda, the second sdb, etc.

Comment: The LLD creates an item for each element of the list the point 1 outputs.

Comment: "Item Prototypes" are being created. I can't make a "key" from them. The data in No. 4 comes in the form ["sda"], but I need it as sda.

Comment: i updated the answer: the [] you are trying to remove are in the key, not in the LLD output

Comment: in this case, an error occurs: "Cannot create item: item with the same key "system.run["smartctl -A /dev/{$DISK}"]" already exists.". It exits for every detected element.

Comment: The data is not substituted into the key and therefore it is the same everywhere. Therefore an error occurs.

Comment: did you already set `zabbix agent` as type of the prototype item?

Comment: That's right. The type of the Item prototype must be a zabbix agent. In my post in №4, "Dependent items" is incorrectly indicated. Therefore, I create an prototype with the "zabbix-agent" type.

Comment: But my data is not substituted if I just specify {$DISK} in the key. Data is substituted only if you specify [{#DISK}] in the key.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to get the data in the desired format using the macro function:

```
Key: system.run["smartctl -A /dev/{{#DISK}.regsub(\"..(...)\", \1)}"]
```